# How to detect view-source scheme in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wish to run a content script when viewing the source of any web page. (and have a page action icon appear)

The [docs here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) don't mention view-source as a valid scheme.

Is there a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert a content-script into `view-source:` pages. 
I didn't found a detailed explanation, but [here is](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=87651&view=revision) the related commit.